# Inserting submenu to main menu using jquery - good idea?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I have main menu showing only first level links (3 items).

```
**Home**
**Themes**
-green
-blue
-red
**Jokes**
-long
-short
-medium
```

I am using [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module (to show second level items) + [Power menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/power_menu) (to make menu items active if current node has certain term).
So when a node with taxonomy "theme" is displayed, the items under "themes" shows up in block menu.

What I would like to do is to somehow inject the block menu items inside primary menu. The main reason is to be able to use responsive menu, that immediately shows user menu options based on node term. (It is more of a usability idea for mobile users - not having to click through full menu).

**Question:** Do you think it is a good idea to inject such menu using jquery? Or is there a better drupal way of doing this? Thank you

Comment: Is it block menu module or Menu block module or Block per menu module, There is nothing called block menu module.

Comment: *The main reason is to be able to use responsive menu, that immediately shows user menu options based on node term.* So, do you want that the menu items gets changed based on the title of the node. Or do you want Main menu, where user just hover on the item or click on the item it opens one small block under that which shown the all options under that particular menu item, so user can see what that main menu items provide under it and user can navigate easily.

Comment: @CodeNext HI, I would like the menu to be changed/altered based on node's taxonomy - this change is happening already - due to the menu_block functionality. The last thing is to move the menu_block items, inside the menu.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is to somehow inject the block menu items
> inside primary menu.
>
> Or is there a better drupal way of doing this?

**[TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu)** allows you to put blocks and view blocks inside your menus. Perhaps you should consider using this module instead.

[image]